# Install phppgadmin and run using localhost (php 7)

Tags: php, xampp, phppgadmin

I have PHP 7 installed in my local computer (XAMPP). I want to install phppgadmin. But it only supports php5.6 it seems. Can someone help me with this, to install phppgadmin with PHP7 on windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried what have you encountered?

Comment: I am trying to install and run two XAMPPs one with php5.6 and another with php7. @AndreiDurnea

Answer (score 0):

Install directly Postgresql with PgAdmin4. You can use it with Xampp

Comment: I tried doing it. But when I start the application it throws error starting application.

Answer (score 0):

after one day struggle by installing two XAMPP with different versions of PHP (7 and 5.6) I could run phppgadmin for PHP5.6 only. But since my Laravel project have dependency of PHP7 on connecting to db I got driver not found. I have decided not to use phppgadmin :( :( . Now I have reached this stage.

[image]

Just want to cretae database and connect. Cheers guys